# Display Placeholder text separately for each input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**I have following code:**

```
    <div>
  <input data-maxsale="9" data-maxsaleid="27595" name="cart[3839][qty]" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty" maxlength="12">
  <div class="maxsalenotifcation maxsaleid-27595">
    <p>
      placeholder
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <input data-maxsale="3" data-maxsaleid="27757" name="cart[3841][qty]" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty" maxlength="12">
  <div class="maxsalenotifcation maxsaleid-27757">
    <p>
      placeholder
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

var maxSalInput = $('input[data-maxsaleid]');
$('.maxsalenotifcation').hide();

maxSaleInputs.each(function() {

  var maxSaleID = $(this).attr('data-maxsaleid');
  var maxSaleValue = $(this).val();
  var maxSaleQuantity = $(this).attr('data-maxsale');

  if (maxSaleValue > maxSaleQuantity) {
    $('.maxsalenotifcation .maxsaleid-' + maxSaleID).show();
  }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bmpqo69g/

I want to display the `placeholder` separately for each `maxsaleid` when the input value is bigger than the `maxSaleValue`.

I can modify the html markup if needed.

How can i do this?

Comment: You have a typo there: `var maxSalInput = ` shoud be `maxSaleInputs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This `maxSaleInputs`variable has not been defined.
2. You should define multiple classes like this `$('.maxsalenotifcation.maxsaleid-' + maxSaleID)` (without space in between classes)

Code Snippets:

```js
$(function() {
  var maxSalInput = $('input[data-maxsaleid]');
  $('.maxsalenotifcation').hide();

  maxSalInput.each(function() {

    var maxSaleID = $(this).attr('data-maxsaleid');
    var maxSaleValue = parseInt($(this).val());
    var maxSaleQuantity = parseInt($(this).attr('data-maxsale'));

    if (maxSaleValue > maxSaleQuantity) {
      $('.maxsalenotifcation.maxsaleid-' + maxSaleID).show();
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input data-maxsale="9" data-maxsaleid="27595" name="cart[3839][qty]" value="10" title="Qty" class="input-text qty" maxlength="12">
  <div class="maxsalenotifcation maxsaleid-27595">
    <p>
      placeholder
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <input data-maxsale="3" data-maxsaleid="27757" name="cart[3841][qty]" value="4" title="Qty" class="input-text qty" maxlength="12">
  <div class="maxsalenotifcation maxsaleid-27757">
    <p>
      placeholder
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Nish. If this answer solved your problem, you can mark it as answer by clicking the tick mark near the answer.